# How to add additional data with uploadStoredFiles?

Tags: jquery, fine-uploader

I want to upload files along with form data. I tried [this](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/forms.html) method, but when the form contains invalid data, ie. invalid email address in `email` field (in this case my server will return a 422 error with an error message), the plugin will mark files as 'upload failed', and after I correct my `email` filed and submit the form again, those 'failed' files won't be uploaded.

So i decided to take another approach, which is upload form data with a ajax call and fire fine-uploader in `success`.

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: ...,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
        var id = data.id;
        $('#files-uploader').fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles')
    }
});
```

My problem is how can I pass `id` into `uploadStoredFiles`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the request.params attribute:

```
var galleryUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
            element: $('#files-uploader'),

            request: {
                endpoint: '/server/uploads',
                params:data.id
            }
        });
```

see:http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#request.params

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: I already initialised `fineUploader`. How can I send `id` when calling `$('#files-uploader').fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles');`

Comment: you reinitialise the plugin with your value